# Any recommendations for books on CFA and SEM, R?

Tags: references

Context:
-Psychology student interested in learning more about CFA and SEM with the use of R.

Recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two books I have referenced in the past. I particularly like the 2015 book as it also goes into other latent variable modeling techniques (e.g., Item Response Theory) in an accessible way. It may also be worth using the lavaan website (also below) as a learning tool, as it has many good examples.

Finch, W. H., & French, B. F. (2015). Latent variable modeling with R. Routledge.

Gana, K., & Broc, G. (2019). Structural equation modeling with lavaan. John Wiley & Sons.

https://www.lavaan.ugent.be/